# Is there any way to ditch Rambi?

Tags: donkey-kong-country-returns

Is there any way to ditch Rambi in Donkey Kong Country Returns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can dismount  from Rambi -- the exact commands differ depending on what control style you're playing with:

> While using the combination Wiimote
>   and Nunchuk, press Z or B to dismount
>   Rambi. If you are playing with the
>   Wiimote horizontally, hold down and
>   press 1 to dismount.

Comment: hold down and press 1... how was i supposed to discover that?? thanks! i just finished what is probably the last rambi level (8-4), so i guess i won't be able to use this knowledge, but thanks anyway!